# Dynamically display element/label when ratio button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide mailingaddress box and label, and also hide comments box and label. They will only show up when I click on the radio button "mail" (the first choice), and when I switch to another button/choice, those labels and fields will be hidden again. Same for comments - when I click on "I accepted" of Terms of Services - the comments box and label will show up, if I uncheck it, the box and the label disappear. I successfully hide them but I cannot make them appear again when I click on the mail button, neither can I make the comments box and label appear when I click on "I accept" of Terms of Services. Where did I go wrong?

```js
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var processEntries = function() {
 var isValid = true;

 // get values for user entries 
    var email = $("email_address").value;
    var phone = $("phone").value;
    var country = $("country").value;
    var terms = $("terms").checked; //return true or false indicates whether a check box is checked or not
 
 //remove validity messages if there is any
 $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent  = ""; 
 $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent  = "";
 $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent  = "";
 $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent  = ""; 
 
 // check user entries for validity
    if (email === "") {
        $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This field is required.";
  isValid = false; 
    }
 
 if (phone === "") {
        $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent  = "This field is required.";
  isValid = false;
    }
 
    if (country === "") {
        $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent  = "Please select a country.";
  isValid = false;
    }
 
 if (terms === false) {
        $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent  = "This box must be checked.";
  isValid = false;
    }
 
    if(isValid)
 {
  $("registration_form").submit();  //submit registration form
 }
};

var resetForm = function() {
    $("registration_form").reset();
 $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
 $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*"; 
 $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*"; 
 $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
    $("email_address").focus();
};

$("register").onclick = processEntries;
$("reset_form").onclick = resetForm;

//step 1: hide mailingaddress box and label, hide comments box and label
document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "none";

document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";

//step 2: define event handler function and add event listener to hide or show mailing address box and label when radio buttons are clicked. 
//show mailing addess box and label only when mail button is clicked, when other buttons are clicked, hide mailing address box and label
document.getElementById("mail").addEventListener("click", displayMailOption);
function displayMailOption() {
 if (documenet.getElementById("mail").checked){
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
  } else {
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
  }
}

//step 3: define event handler functionn and add event listener to hide or show comment box and label when check box is clicked. 
//show comment box and label only when check box is checked. when check box is unchecked, hide comment box and label
document.getElementById("comments").addEventListener("click", displayCommentOption);
function displayCommentOption() {
 if (documenet.getElementById("comments").checked){
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
  } else {
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
html { background-image: url("ginkgo.jpg");}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
 
    width: 730px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 150%;
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 9em;
}
input, select , textarea{
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
input[type="checkbox"],[type="radio"] { 
    width: 1em;
}

#registration_form span {
    color: red;
 font-size: 80%;
}

.hide {display: none;}
input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 1.4em;}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #000;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Account Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register.css">

</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Register for an Account</h1>
    <form action="register_account.html" method="get"
        name="registration_form" id="registration_form">
    
        <label for="email_address">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address">
            <span>*</span><br>
        <label for="phone">Mobile Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
            <span>*</span><br>
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
            <select name="country" id="country">
             <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option>USA</option>
                <option>Canada</option>
                <option>Mexico</option>
            </select>
            <span>*</span><br>
        <label>Contact me by:</label>         
            <input type="radio" name="contact" id="mail" value="mail">Mail
            <input type="radio" name="contact" id="email" value="email">Email
   <input type="radio" name="contact" id="mphone" value="mobilephone">Mobile Phone
      <input type="radio" name="contact" id="none" value="none">Don't contact me
        <br>
   
  <label for="mailingaddress">Your Mailing Address:</label>
  <textarea id="mailingaddress"></textarea><br>
  
        <label>Terms of Service:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="yes">I accept
            <span>*</span><br>
     
  <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
  <textarea id="comments" cols='20'  rows='10' ></textarea><br>
  
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="register" value="Register">
        <input type="button" id="reset_form" value="Reset">
    </form>
</main>
<script src="register.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code has runtime errors  (i.e. it's `document`, not `documenet`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have event listeners for other radio inputs, so no code will run.
   Add these:

```
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("click", displayMailOption);
document.getElementById("mphone").addEventListener("click", displayMailOption);
document.getElementById("none").addEventListener("click", displayMailOption);
```

Now on every radio input change, your `displayMailOption` function will run.

2. The `displayMailOption` function should look like this, after fixing the typo and selecting the correct element:

```
function displayMailOption() {
    if (document.getElementById("mail").checked) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

3. Fix the comment listener ID:

```
document.getElementById("terms").addEventListener("click", displayCommentOption);
```

4. The `displayCommentOption` function should look like this:

```
function displayCommentOption() {
    if (document.getElementById("terms").checked) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code did run for the comment section, but not the mailing section. Any idea to fix it? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh please don't mind me! It worked! I just fixed my silly typos!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need JavaScript to achieve that. You can do it in pure CSS. But to answer your question first, the problem is that you attach the click event the label and the function is called only when input is clicked. So if "email", "phone" or other labels are clicked the function is not called and therefore the elements are not hidden.

Here is an example of how to do it using only CSS:

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var processEntries = function() {
  var isValid = true;

  // get values for user entries 
  var email = $("email_address").value;
  var phone = $("phone").value;
  var country = $("country").value;
  var terms = $("terms").checked; //return true or false indicates whether a check box is checked or not

  //remove validity messages if there is any
  $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";

  // check user entries for validity
  if (email === "") {
    $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (phone === "") {
    $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (country === "") {
    $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent = "Please select a country.";
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (terms === false) {
    $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This box must be checked.";
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (isValid) {
    $("registration_form").submit(); //submit registration form
  }
};

var resetForm = function() {
  $("registration_form").reset();
  $("email_address").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
  $("phone").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
  $("country").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
  $("terms").nextElementSibling.textContent = "*";
  $("email_address").focus();
};

$("register").onclick = processEntries;
$("reset_form").onclick = resetForm;

//step 1: hide mailingaddress box and label, hide comments box and label
/*
document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "none";

document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
*/
//step 2: define event handler function and add event listener to hide or show mailing address box and label when radio buttons are clicked. 
//show mailing addess box and label only when mail button is clicked, when other buttons are clicked, hide mailing address box and label
//document.getElementById("mail").addEventListener("click", displayMailOption);
/*
function displayMailOption() {
  if (document.getElementById("mail").checked) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
  }
}

//step 3: define event handler functionn and add event listener to hide or show comment box and label when check box is clicked. 
//show comment box and label only when check box is checked. when check box is unchecked, hide comment box and label
document.getElementById("comments").addEventListener("click", displayCommentOption);

function displayCommentOption() {
  if (document.getElementById("comments").checked) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
  }
}
*/
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url("ginkgo.jpg");
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 0 2em 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 9em;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  width: 1em;
}

#registration_form span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 1.4em;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #000;
}


/* Hide elements on load */

#mailingaddress,
#mailadress-label,
#comments-label,
#comments {
  display: none;
}


/* Show elements when #mail is checked */

#mail:checked~#mailingaddress,
#mail:checked~#mailadress-label {
  display: block;
}


/* Show comments when #terms is checked */

#terms:checked~#comments-label,
#terms:checked~#comments {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Register for an Account</h1>
  <form action="register_account.html" method="get" name="registration_form" id="registration_form">

    <label for="email_address">E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address">
    <span>*</span><br>
    <label for="phone">Mobile Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
    <span>*</span><br>
    <label for="country">Country:</label>
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value="">Select an option</option>
      <option>USA</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Mexico</option>
    </select>
    <span>*</span><br>
    <label>Contact me by:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" id="mail" value="mail">Mail
    <input type="radio" name="contact" id="email" value="email">Email
    <input type="radio" name="contact" id="mphone" value="mobilephone">Mobile Phone
    <input type="radio" name="contact" id="none" value="none">Don't contact me
    <br>

    <label for="mailingaddress" id='mailadress-label'>Your Mailing Address:</label>
    <textarea id="mailingaddress"></textarea><br>

    <label>Terms of Service:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="yes">I accept
    <span>*</span><br>

    <label for="comments" id='comments-label'>Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="comments" cols='20' rows='10'></textarea><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="register" value="Register">
    <input type="button" id="reset_form" value="Reset">
  </form>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("mail").checked){
     document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "block";
   } else {
     document.getElementsByTagName("label")[4].style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("mailingaddress").style.display = "none";
  }
})


document.getElementById("terms").addEventListener("click", displayCommentOption);
function displayCommentOption() {
  if (document.getElementById("terms").checked){
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "block";
  } else {
   document.getElementsByTagName("label")[6].style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```